# Counting the number of rows of a result table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a table that shows the results of a database table and there is a cell of the result of number of files in the database. It looks like this

```
<?php
include ('../../include/dbConnect.php');
include ('../include/header.php');
include ('../include/checkAdmin.php');



$sql = "SELECT * from categories";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0)

    ?>


<div class="text">
<h2>Categoties</h2>
    <form class="action" action="add.php" method="POST">
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="add_category">Add Category</button>
</form></div>
<br>
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th width= "300"><a href='?order=category'>Category</a></th>
                <th colspan="3" width= "150">Action</th>
                <th width= "150">Number of files</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 

    <?php
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()):    ?>

        <tr>

                <td><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
                <td>
    <form action='edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="edit_btn" >Edit</button></form></td>

    <td>   
    <form action='list.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="list_btn" >Files</button></form> </td>   
    <td>
    <form action='delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Delete">
    </form></td>
    <td><?php  $query = "SELECT * from files WHERE category_id =" . $row['category'];
                $res = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                $r = mysql_num_rows($res); 
                **echo** 
                ?></td>

    </tr>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </tbody>
    </table><br>

<?php include('../include/footer.php');
?>
```

I want to echo the number of the files that are in every category. As you can see the tables are connected with category_id.

Answer (score 1):

Use [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) to get the number of rows.

You can use the below-given query to fix your issue -

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) from files WHERE category_id =" . $row['category'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><?php $query = "SELECT count(*) from files WHERE category_id =" . $row['category']; 
          $res = mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
          $r = mysql_num_rows($res); 
          echo $r;
?></td>
```

I am getting mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given